# Passar valor de uma variável php para uma variável JS de outro arquivo php

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho o seguinte codigo no meu arquivo finalizar-compra.php:

```
          <script>
            var delivery = "<?php echo $sub_total; ?>";
            var reitrada = "<?php echo $total; ?>";
            var cupom = 
          

            function addEventHandler(elem, eventType, handler) {
              if (elem.addEventListener)
                elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
              else if (elem.attachEvent)
                elem.attachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
            }

            addEventHandler(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
              addEventHandler(document.getElementById('tipoentrega'), 'change', function() {
                if (document.getElementById("tipoentrega").value == 'Delivery') {
                  valor = delivery;
                } else {
                  valor = reitrada;
                }
                console.log(valor);
                document.getElementById('total').value = valor;

              });
            });


          </script>
          </input>
```

Basciamente esse código verifica se o usuario selecionou a opção delivery e adiciona a taxa de entrega no valor final da compra.

Tenho tambem esse código no arquivo validarDesconto.

```html
<?php 


include_once ("conexao.php");


if(isset($_POST['cupom'])){ 

$buscacupom = $_POST['cupom'];
        
    $conscupom = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cupom WHERE nome='$buscacupom'");
    $conscupom->execute();

    $sql = "SELECT valor FROM cupom WHERE nome='$buscacupom'";

    $valorcupom = $pdo->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    $fetchAll = $conscupom->fetchAll();
        
    if ($conscupom->rowCount() == 0)
        {
            
        }
    else{
        echo json_encode(array('cupom' => 'R$'.$valorcupom['valor'].',00')); 

        }
    }


        ?>
```

Ele verifica no banco se o cupom digitado existe ou não no banco e retorna o valor do cupom dentro de um strong na página finalizar-compra.php

A minha dúvida é:
O valor do cupom é salvo dentro da variável $valorcupom no arquivo validarDesconto.php. Como eu passo esse valor para uma variável JS, assim somando no if citado la no começo. Vou exemplificar:
Eu precisaria que o IF ficasse assim:

```html
if (document.getElementById("tipoentrega").value == 'Delivery') {
                      valor = delivery + valordesconto;
                    } else {
                      valor = reitrada + valordesconto;
                    }
```

O valordesconto teria o valor da variável $valorcupom que busca no banco no arquivo validarDesconto.php

Comment: No caso, o arquivo JS que recebe a variável do PHP está no mesmo arquivo PHP ou em arquivo diferente?

Comment: Quem faz a busca do valor e armazena em uma variável php é o validarDesconto.php e quem precisa receber o valor da variável php em uma variável JS é o arquivo finalziar-compra.php. Os dois arquivos são PHP e o script JS fica dentro do arquivo finalziar-compra.php

Answer (score -2):

Vou fazer em exemplo para você pela quarta forma.

1. Se você não quiser sair da página validarDesconto.php você pode usar o AJAX.

Página: validarDesconto.php

```
<?php 

$variavel_a_ser_passada = 100;

?>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="variavel" value="<?php echo $variavel_a_ser_passada; ?>"/>
    <!--Se não quiser que tenha botão de enviar, você pode retirar do HTML e enviar com a função submit() do javascript. Ou então coloque um style="display:none" nele. Porém, acho melhor efetuar o click pelo javascript (pois o display:none pode demorar de carregar o estilo um pouco), mas vai de preferências-->
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault() //Impede sair da página
            var dados = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "finalziar-compra.php",
                cache: false,
                //Esses código abaixo podem ser retirados se quiser, pois não afetam o funcionamento do código.
                data: dados,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log("ERRO"+data)
                }
            });
            
        });
    });
</script>
```

Página: finalziar-compra.php

```
<?php 

$variavel = $_POST["variavel"];

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var variavelVinda = "<?php echo $variavel; ?>"
    /*Observe que a variável talvez venha como String.
     Para converter para número, existe 2 formas: 
     1 - Faça:

     variavelNova = new Number(variavelVinda)

     Ou faça:

     variavelNova = variavel*1
     */
</script>
```

Agora, se você quiser sair da página validarDesconto.php, basta retirar o e.preventDefault() ou então, para ficar um código mais resumido, pode elimiar o Jquery e fazer um evento submit do próprio javascript no formulário.

Comment: Junte as suas duas respostas em uma. O Stack Overflow não é fórum, somos um site de perguntas e respostas, da maneira que publicou o conteúdo ele está fora do nosso formato. Veja [answer].

Answer (score -3):

Existem várias formas de fazer isto.
Formas:

1. Fazer um require_once no PHP ( Pior forma que considero, pois essa função envia todo o conteúdo do PHP )
2. Fazer uma conexão XML com a função XMLHttpRequest do Javascript (Segunda pior forma que considero, já que esta função envia somente o conteúdo interpretado pelo PHP -> É melhor que a primeira, porém têm esse probleminha)
3. Usar o IMPORT e EXPORT do Javascript (Uma das melhores forma que considero, já que com estas funções eu posso exportar somente a variável)
4. Enviar um POST de uma página PHP para outra. E se não quiser sair da página, basta enviar com AJAX o valor. (Uma forma que considero boa também, pois não necessita enviar todo o conteúdo de uma página, somente a variável )

...

Se você queiser aprender sobre a terceira opção, recomendo este vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Avdyl8YgWg

Comment: Entendi a sua resposta. Eu assisti o vídeo da terceira opção, mas ele mostra a importação e a exportação entre dois arquivos JS certo? No caso, eu precisaria exportar o valor de uma variável PHP para uma variável JS de outro arquivo PHP. Se possível, me mostra um exemplo da 4 opção

Comment: Não interaja com o autor da pergunta ou outros usuários através das respostas. Se precisar interagir ou oferecer orientação adicional use o campo de comentários.